# Mongodb Match items in array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query an array in Mongo with an array of tags.
As an example from the documentation, below is my dataset

```
{
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, tags: ["red", "blank"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, tags: ["red", "blank", "plain"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, tags: ["blue"], dim_cm: [ 10, 15.25 ] }
}
```

I want to query the tags with an array `["red", "black"]` which will find results where tags contains red OR black

I can do it where it gives me the results for items where tags are red AND black using 
`db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red", "blank"] } } )`

How do I go about making this an OR query?

Comment: may be this `db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      tags: "red"
    },
    {
      tags: "black"
    }
  ]
})` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use or operator. This will find documents that contain tags as black or red.

```
db.collection.find({
$or: [
{
  tags: "red"
},
{
  tags: "black"
}
]
});
```

tested it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rz_scGtT5z9

Comment: Hmm it still fails here `.find({ userId: 'uzNWm9YF0rZbDkrIyPLKz9owUSO2', tags: { '$or': [ { tags: '94HhqHzrhLl4kYWYRuVv' }, { tags: '5HYgQEbIKhb36SZNRihM' } ] } }`  Unknown operator $or

Comment: Ah, I see, the $or operator needs to be at the parent level, not within the tags itself.

Answer (score -1):

Move $all for a $or and it should do the work.

http://www.querymongo.com/

Maybe it'll help

Comment: Hmm `MongoError: unknown operator: $or`

Comment: Faraz got it (I just started programming actualy and figured it would look like sql statements with and/or/all/any)